# Redirect non-www to www using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I access a file on my root like **example.com/demo/provider** it is redirecting to **www.example.com**.

How can I correct this so that it will redirect correctly to **www.example.com/demo/provider**

**What I have tried:**

**Try 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Try 2**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Try 3**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried some other codes too, **Any suggestions will be appreciated** Thanks!

**Note:** *I already searched options available on Stackoverflow. But, none of answer worked for me. So, its not a duplicate question. I respect rules and terms of site.*

**My .htaccess file is in provider folder. You can take it as sub domain/directory.**

Comment: Be sure to clear your cache when testing out redirects, especially considering you're using a 301 permanent redirect. You can also open your dev-tools and ensure cache is turned off while dev tools is open. Then leave it open, and load up the URL again. Note: always better to test with a 302 redirect, so the browser doesn't cache it.

Comment: @MikeRockett I already working on it by turning off cache for my browser and I am also clearing site cache after each change. As per your suggestion I tried to go with 302, but still facing same issue. Any other suggestions or idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your htaccess is in the /provider folder  then you have to use the full path to dir in  target url,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/demo/provider/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will correctly redirect your url from :

- http://example.com/dir/foobar

to

- http://www.example.com/dir/foobar